# How To Extract Span Class using iMacros?

Tags: imacros

How can I extract "tt0463985" from this using iMacros?

```html
<span class="wlb_wrapper" data-tconst="tt0463985" data-size="small" data-caller-name="search"></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
TAG POS=1 TYPE=SPAN ATTR=CLASS:wlb_wrapper EXTRACT=HTM
```

Then you can use EVENT to get the part you want.

Comment: How to do it? with details

Comment: Not 'EVENT' but 'EVAL()'... I'll post the Solution @OP if you are still watching this Thread and still want the Answer... (+ Mention your FCI... (Full Config Info))

Answer (score 0):

Hope that helps you

```
 TAG POS=1 TYPE=SPAN ATTR=CLASS:wlb_wrapper&&data-tconst:*
```